# How can I set the LIMIT 1, 4 in doctrine dql

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

So is it possible to set the starting point in MySQL LIMIT via the doctrine?

All I know is how to setMaxResults()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Query::setFirstResult($offset)`. [See more here.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only)